# Why is sonar only analyzes pom.xml´s?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have a multi module java-maven project with the sonarQube dependency working fine, but it only analyzes the pom.xml archives and not te source code.

I think the problem is in the properties, but i dont know what to try (I´m very new with sonar).

This is the structure of the main pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>UVRCI</groupId>
  <artifactId>UVRCI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
      <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000/</sonar.host.url>
      <sonar.sources>src/main/java,pom.xml</sonar.sources>
  </properties>


  <modules>
      <module>../UVRCIEJB</module>
      <module>../UVRCISrc</module>
      <module>../UVRCIUtil</module>
      <module>../UVRCIWSJ</module>
      <module>../UVRCIWeb</module>
  </modules>

<dependencies>......</dependencies>
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

I have no errors on the report, but only the pom.xml files appear.

Thanks for the help

Comment: So, what's exactly your question?

Comment: where are you analyzing the sonar results, on the sonarqube portal or with the sonar plugin on eclipse

Comment: I want the sonar to analyze all the program files (java-classes).
I am using the sonarQube portal with my own database.

Comment: Probably the problem is in the sonar-project.properties file, could you please post it ?

Comment: when you use sonar in maven the properties are writen on the pom.xml(posted on the code up above), not on the sonar-project.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below profiles it will check all the bugs in your project as per the rules set in your sonarqube portal and also show the test coverage of your application when mvn test is ran.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar-coverage</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.8</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>agent-for-it</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```